# Sending MySql data as SMS, via Twilio

Tags: python, mysql, sms, twilio

I'd like to receive an SMS reminder which I have submitted to a database (via web form, not via SMS). For example (in python):

```
    message = client.sms.messages.create(to"---phone number1---", from_="---phone number2---", body="message text yay!")
```

Sends "message text yay!" to "phone number2" from the Twilio number.

I'd like to send information listed in a MySql database, rather than a single text item as shown above. (Solutions need not be in Python only.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, the best way would probably be to fetch the SMS information out of the database and then send the SMS messages using Twilio in the application layer. For example, [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/myconnpy_example_cursor_select.html) are some guides to turning data from a MySQL database into Python variables.

You could then use the [twilio-python SMS library](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-python) to send the SMS messages.